# How do I declare a 2D array whose each element contains two values in python? Also, please guide me if there is any better data structure to do this

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I want to declare a N*N 2D array in python where each element is a 1*2 element itself - current iteration value, TRUE

For N = 2 the 2*2 matrix should look something like this -

```
0,TRUE   1,TRUE  2,TRUE
3,TRUE   4,TRUE  5,TRUE
6,TRUE   7,TRUE  8,TRUE
```

I tried initializing a 2D array and then iterated over it and set each value to [count, TRUE] but it doesn't work.

```
def some_method(self, N):
     self.N = N
     self.array = [[0 for x in range(self.N)]  for y in range(self.N)]
     self.count = 0
        for i in range(self.N):
            for j in range(0,i+1):
                self.array[i][j] = [self.count, False]
                self.count = self.count + 1
```

Output for N = 2-

```
[[[0, TRUE], 0], [[1, TRUE], [2, TRUE]]]
```

REQUIRED Output -

```
[[[0,TRUE],[1,TRUE],[2,TRUE]], [[3,TRUE],[4,TRUE],[5,TRUE]], [[6,TRUE],[7,TRUE],[8,TRUE]]]
```

Please also let me know if there is some better way of storing and accessing such data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking it. This will simply produce your desired output:

```
self.array = [[[0, True] for x in range(self.N)] for y in range(self.N)]
```

which makes an `x`-length list where each element is `[0, True]`, and then makes a `y`-length list where each element is the `x`-length list.

That aside, your iteration is also off. When you do `for j in range(0,i+1):`, you're iterating *relative to the `i` you're also counting in the first place*. If you want to hit *every* element of the matrix, then you need to iterate through the axes independently:

```
self.array = [[0 for x in range(self.N)]  for y in range(self.N)]
self.count = 0
for i in range(self.N):  # you could also use range(len(self.array)), since the length of self.array will be self.N
    for j in range(self.N):  # you could also use range(len(self.array[i])), since the length of the ith row of self.array will be self.N
        self.array[i][j] = [self.count, False]
        self.count += 1
```